# mac os El Capitan подключение 3g/gprs через bluetooth

Tags: mac, bluetooth, ос

После установки El Capitan со всеми обновлениями перестал работать интернет через обычный телефон подключенный через bluetooth. На Yosemite работало, а сейчас нет таких настроек. Как можно решить проблему выхода в интернет через телефон в качестве bluetooth модема?

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас у них тестовая бета версия, и соответственно могут быть очень много багов. Проблему надо направлять в компанию APple  через встроенный ассистент обратной связи и ждать обновления от них.